# Wrong error C2039 in VS2012 with a C++/CLI

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2012, c++-cli

I have a project using C++/CLI. Then I have an event handler like this one:

```
void NotificationSystemEventHandler::NotificationServiceDetailViewRequested(System::Object^ sender, Notifications::NotificationViewer::DetailViewOpenRequestedEventArgs^ e)
{
    try
    {
        switch (e->Type->ID)
        {
            (...)
```

The class `DetailViewOpenRequestedEventArgs` has one property called `Type` of type `DomainModel::CMN::NotificationType^`

Then the `NotificationType` class has a property called ID of type int. When I'm accessing the property I get a C2039 saying that ID is not a member of `NotificationType` when it really is as I can see the property on the Object Browser.

The only strange thing is that Intellisense gives an error when trying to find the type and says that the type has no members but seems as the compiler can still resolve the type correctly but not its members.

I'm using the class at several other places. I can supply more info / images if requested to help clarify things.

These are the images of the issue:

The error message:
[image: The error message]

The object browser:
[image: The object browser]

The wrong popup:
[image]

Comment: The property ID is just an int.

Comment: Seems that there is something wrong with the references on the project. The reference dialog shows some references as added (with the check-box checked) but they do not appear at the references item of the project on the solution explorer .... weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing all the references and adding them again to the project solved the issue ....